# HTML content textfield not working

Tags: html, iphone, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have include the following code in my sencha project to test in iphone, in HTML content,when i click Text field. is not enabled or not showing key board .,But the buttons working responds properly

```
var additemspnl = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    id: 'additemspnl',
    scrollable:'vertical',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
   html:'<div style="padding:10px;"><input type="text" class="txtfield" id="tx   titemname" placeholder="ITEM NAME" />
         <br><input class="txtfield" id="txtitemdesc" type="text" placeholder="ITEM DESCRIPTION"/><br><input class="txtfield"  id="txtprice" type="range" name="points" min="1" max="10000">
         <br><input type="number" class="txtfield" id="txtitemprice" placeholder="PRICE"/><div>
         <table style="padding:0px;margin-bottom:0px;"><tr><td align="center"><img src="resources/img/iconaddimage.png" id="productpic" /></td>
         <td align="center"><img src="resources/img/iconshowlocation.png" id="imglocation" /></td></tr></table></div>
         <input type="text" class="txtfield" placeholder="SHOW LOCATION" id="txtlocation"/><br>
         <input type="text" class="txtfield" placeholder="WISH CATEGORY"/><br>
         <input type="text" class="txtfield" id="txtshopurl" placeholder="SHOP NAME OR URL"/><div align="center" style="padding-top:20px;">
         <img src="resources/img/buttondone.png" id="btndone"></div></div>',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            ui:'light',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Add items'
               }]
        });
```

What changed should i want to do enable the text field?PLease help me

Comment: I didn't understand, what you want to do?

Comment: When i click the textfield, The key boards is not showing in the iphone

Answer (score 0):

I found two problems with the posted code.

1) The html string wasn't dealing with the multiple lines correctly so I  had to concatenate each line to form one string.

2) I had to change the height and width properties to fullscreen: true.

I was able to get the html form and toolbar to show correctly, and they iOS keyboard was usable after these two changes.

**Reformatted code**

```
    var additemspnl = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        id: 'additemspnl',
        scrollable:'vertical',
        fullscreen: true,
        html:'<div style="padding:10px;"><input type="text" class="txtfield" id="tx   titemname" placeholder="ITEM NAME" />' +
        '<br><input class="txtfield" id="txtitemdesc" type="text" placeholder="ITEM DESCRIPTION"/><br><input class="txtfield"  id="txtprice" type="range" name="points" min="1" max="10000">' +
        '<br><input type="number" class="txtfield" id="txtitemprice" placeholder="PRICE"/><div>' +
        '<table style="padding:0px;margin-bottom:0px;"><tr><td align="center"><img src="resources/img/iconaddimage.png" id="productpic" /></td>' +
        '<td align="center"><img src="resources/img/iconshowlocation.png" id="imglocation" /></td></tr></table></div>' +
        '<input type="text" class="txtfield" placeholder="SHOW LOCATION" id="txtlocation"/><br>' +
        '<input type="text" class="txtfield" placeholder="WISH CATEGORY"/><br> ' +
        '<input type="text" class="txtfield" id="txtshopurl" placeholder="SHOP NAME OR URL"/><div align="center" style="padding-top:20px;">' +
        '<img src="resources/img/buttondone.png" id="btndone"></div></div>',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            ui:'light',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Add items'
        }],            
    });
```

Note: You may want to look into the Sencha Touch's Form Panel to do form UI, instead of doing raw html.

There's an example of it [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/example/kitchen-sink).  Click on User Interface, then Forms.  You can view the source as well.